# How to write a infinite array program in c

Tags: arrays, c

how to define an int array of 100 elements and use an infinite loop to sequentially print the value of each array element by keep increasing the array index without limit. I am confused about whether reading pass the array bound immediately crash the program or not? And if it does, then can it crash at the same array index? the array elements initialized or not? values all zero? Are they the same across different execution runs?

Comment: The first sentence of your post doesn't make any sense.  Why would you use an infinite loop on a finite array?

Comment: Reading out-of-bounds invokes *undefined behavior* and anything is allowed to happen then.

Comment: Try it out. The worst you can do is crash your program.

Comment: Your best case scenario is that you get a page fault and the program quits without damaging your computer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and worst case you get to live through Event Horizon

Comment: It is also *undefined behaviour* to print the values of the array elements when they have not been initialised, even if the index is within bounds.

Comment: @MadPhysicist from the amount of UB I see, if those "nasal demon" stories were anything but tales to scare children, we would all have evaporated long ago ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane. Could be the survivorship bias talking :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist "dead men tell no tales" – except for those who went through the event horizon, but they are having trouble messaging me.

Comment: As a mere remark on *nasal demons*, I can still remember MS/DOS and Win3 where a single program error could easily crash the system. Now the process memory isolation is a fact, it generally only crashes the faulty process. But the language wording is conservative...

Comment: Hmm, I think Window's [Blue screen of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death) does still happen, even if another colour now.

Answer (score 4):

Once you read or write past the bounds of an array, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once your program has undefined behavior, anything can happen.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or it could appear to run properly.

So it could crash after going past 1 element, 1000 elements or 1000000 elements.  Just because the program *could* crash doesn't necessarily mean it *will*.